# How can I get a list of all individual imports in a ts file with their absolute paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

What I am looking for:

Assume `a.tsx`

```
import X from './x.js';
import { Y, Z } from 'src/path/to/file.ts';
```

I want a list like this

- X - someRootLocation/path/to/x.js
- Y - someRootLocation/path/to/file.ts
- Z - someRootLocation/path/to/file.ts

Ideally, it will be better if the program can recursively do this till the leaf nodes but it's okay even if I get it for the current file only.

Please note, this is not as easy as parsing the file and using string manipulation due to relative paths and aliases set up with webpack. I am looking for absolute paths only.

---

I tried using [madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) but it only is limited to the path of an import which means if I am importing multiple stuff from a file, it only returns once the path of that file and does not list out the things that I actually imported.

Comment: You'll probably need to parse your source files, as [there is no built-in readable cache for ESM like `require.cache` has](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2806#issuecomment-650653295).

Answer (score 0):

Needs node & typescript, run with the filename as a param, it outputs each one import per line...

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import { readFileSync } from "node:fs";
import ts from "typescript";

const tsHost = ts.createCompilerHost(
  {
    allowJs: true,
    noEmit: true,
    isolatedModules: true,
    resolveJsonModule: false,
    moduleResolution: ts.ModuleResolutionKind.Classic, // we don't want node_modules
    incremental: true,
    noLib: true,
    noResolve: true,
  },
  true,
);

function delintNode(node) {
  if (!ts.isImportDeclaration(node)) {
    ts.forEachChild(node, delintNode);
    return;
  }

  const named = node.importClause?.namedBindings?.elements || [];
  const name = node.importClause?.name?.escapedText;
  const nname = node.importClause?.namedBindings?.name?.escapedText;
  const from = node.moduleSpecifier.text;
  const typeonly = node.importClause?.isTypeOnly;

  if (name) {
    console.log(typeonly ? "import type" : "import", name, "from", `'${from}';`);
  }

  if (nname) {
    console.log("import * as", nname, "from", `'${from}';`);
  }

  named.forEach(({ name, propertyName, isTypeOnly }) => {
    console.log(
      typeonly || isTypeOnly ? "import { type" : "import {",
      propertyName
        ? `${propertyName.escapedText} as ${name.escapedText}`
        : name.escapedText,
      "} from",
      `'${from}';`,
    );
  });

  if (!name && !nname && !named.length) {
    console.log("import", `'${from}';`);
  }
}

function getImports(fileName) {
  const sourceFile = tsHost.getSourceFile(
    fileName,
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
    (msg) => {
      throw new Error(`Failed to parse ${fileName}: ${msg}`);
    },
  );

  if (!sourceFile) {
    throw ReferenceError(`Failed to find file ${fileName}`);
  }

  delintNode(sourceFile);
}

getImports(process.argv[2]);
```